# ios - UIScrollview w/ autolayout on Xcode 6

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, constraints

I have been struggling for days with this implementation, and even though I have tried to do every tutorial I found on the web, I still cannot make things work the way I want.

Basically, I am trying to put my login form in a scrollview, so that it takes the whole screen at first (and on all iPhones / iPads), and if the keyboard appears everything should move. The problem IS, my view doesn't take the whole screen... Either it is too large, or too high, even though in Interface Builder everything seams correct (from layout to constraints). Below and image of the layout I want to achieve (I am using an universal storyboard, with Size Classes and Autolayout enabled):

http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/829115app.png

Can someone point me out on achieving this layout ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest pinning top, leading and trailing spaces of your scroll view to its superview. And set a bottom space constraint less or equal to the keyboard's height if you set it to 0, the scroll view won't be able to resize.

With your form layout set vertical center constraints and top space to superview constraints for your top label being more or equal than the distance you set in the  IB, and then you can set relative space constraints between each of the components.

Hope I answered your question.

Edit: Just the provided project and got it working. I think the problem is caused by it being a containerView inside a scrollView. And both the container and the scrollViews content view adapt to the size of its subviews. Because of that, setting relative constraints won't help.

What I did was to set an explicit size (screen's size) to the containerView and setting `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)` to it.

I modified your project and uploaded it [here](https://github.com/deivuh/ScrollAndContainerViewsWithAutoLayout-iOS-example)

Comment: I don't know the keyboard height in Interface Builder, since it doesn't show up at start. I am able to scroll dynamically the scrollview by binding the event keyboardDidShow, and that works fine. 

The problem is with the form layout. I can design it well in the Interface Builder, but either it shows up too large and the view scrolls horizontally, or too long and the view scrolls vertically. I want the scrollview to be fullscreen and without scrolling, unless I scroll it on keyboardDidShow

The tutorials told me to put a container view in the scroll and put content there, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @LucioMerotta Could you post screenshots of your view both in IB and running on the simulator?

Comment: Yeah sure! You'll find the screenshots [here](http://pho.to/7i3zC) in order:
- constraints
- layout in interface builder
- screenshots of the iOS simulator

Comment: @Lucio Hey, I think you are having the [same trouble I was having just yesterday with TableViews](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645226/autoresize-cell-xib-to-tableview-cell-width-and-row-height/26647096#26647096). The thing is, you did not set constraints to your scrollView. Since in iOS8 Size Classes were introduced, the views in IB are larger by default, so your scrollView remained the same size as you set in IB. Try to pin the top, leading and trailing spaces of your scrollView to the superview. You are having a scrollView larger than your screen.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! That is what I did! I pinned the top (+20 pts for the statusbar), trailing, leading and bottom spaces of the scrollView to the superview, and the top, trailing, leading and bottom spaces of the Container View to the Superview. I tried to redo this but still the same result as in my screenshot...

Comment: @Lucio I see, then it might be that the contentSize of your scrollView kept the same size, try to set your scrollView's contentSize's width same as your screen's to see what happens.

Comment: already tried with "scrollView.contentSize.width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width" and then calling setNeedsLayout and setNeedsDisplay, still the same behaviour. It seems that the problem comes from my Container View (the white one in the scrollView), that doesn't resize to fit the screen. I tried to resize it programmatically but it didn't work either though...

Comment: @Lucio if you are trying to resize your container view programmatically too, make sure that it doesn't have any constraints set.

Comment: The container view does not have any width/height constraints. Only the subviews have (label, buttons, etc). And when I log my changes the width goes from 600 to 320 (iPhone 4S simulator), so the resizing kinda works. Maybe if I upload the project on a filehost and post the link here it could help to understand how the layout is done ?

Comment: @Lucio sure , and I'll check it once I get home

Comment: [here you go](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0k1emk9k2a5aba5/Snap%20It%21.zip?dl=0)! Thanks

Comment: Thanks that worked ! You rescued me from 3 days of headache !